# setTimeout stops working in case of page error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I am using setTimeout to refresh page,where the jquery template items will be updated. related code are listed as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
         var results = JSON.parse('@svgPath'.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));  

           window.onload = setupRefresh;

           function setupRefresh() {
             setTimeout("refreshPage();", 300); // milliseconds
            }
          function refreshPage() {

            $("#resultTemplate").tmpl(results, {
                checkLink : function(key) {
                 var linkRes = this.data[key];
                 checkFile(linkRes, callbackFunc); 
                 alert("refreshed?");
                return window.myRet;
                 }
            }).appendTo("#resultList" ); 
            }
    </script>
```

Jquery template:

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        <li> 
            {{if  $item.checkLink("link") == 1}}
                  <a href = ${link}>${type}</a> 
            {{else}}
            ${type}
            {{/if}} 
        </li> 
    </script>
```

When I run my app, it seems that if the link is not available (where the ajax function `checkFile(linkRes, callbackFunc);` can cause 404 not found error, then the timer seems to stop. 
But what I want the timer to continuously to execute, that is, the `refreshPage` continues to be called. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` executes the function once. What would make it execute more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusing asynchronous code and synchronous code. You should be attaching a setTimeout to the end of the onSuccess and onFailure events of your ajax. As written your assuming the AJAX call will return the status of the request. However, being asynchronous it will return **before** it receives anything from the server.

To give a simple answer as to what function will repeat over time, your were thinking that `setInterval` would solve your problem. `setInterval` can provide a (somewhat problematic) repeat unlike `setTimeout` which executes once.

Again your will need to establish a pattern in your code that will use `setTimeout` as a continuance from within your AJAX callbacks.